# Laravel DB::raw reading the second parameter in where clause a string in stead of dynamic column from another table

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a query whose variables are being read as strings. It looks like this:

```
$contracts = DB::table('completed_contracts')
            ->select(

                DB::raw("((count(completed_contracts.id)))  as `numOfCompletedContracts`"),
                DB::raw("((count(awarded_contracts.id)))  as `numOfCompletedLate`")
            )
            ->leftJoin('awarded_contracts', function($q) {
                $q
                ->on('completed_contracts.awarded_contract_id', '=', 'awarded_contracts.id')
                ->whereDate('awarded_contracts.completion_date','<','completed_contracts.actual_completion_date');
            })
            ->get();
```

When i do a `Print_r(DB::getQueryLog());`, the query that is output looks like this:

```
SELECT
    (
        (COUNT(completed_contracts.id))
    ) AS `numOfCompletedContracts`,
    ((COUNT(awarded_contracts.id))) AS `numOfCompletedLate`
FROM
    `completed_contracts`
LEFT JOIN `awarded_contracts` ON `completed_contracts`.`awarded_contract_id` = `awarded_contracts`.`id` AND `awarded_contracts`.`completion_date` < 'completed_contracts.actual_completion_date'.
```

How do i ensure that the `completed_contracts.actual_completion_date` is not read as a string in the where clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you are using `whereDate()` incorrectly, which, according to the Laravel [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#where-clauses), is supposed to be used like this:

```
->whereDate('created_at', '2016-12-31')
```

That is, you pass a date column as the *first* parameter, and a date *literal* as the *second* parameter.  Apparently, your code is running, but not in the way you intend.  I think your call to `whereDate` should actually just be another condition in the `ON` clause.  Try using this version:

```
$contracts = DB::table('completed_contracts cc')
    ->select(DB::raw("COUNT(cc.id) AS numOfCompletedContracts"),
             DB::raw("COUNT(ac.id) AS numOfCompletedLate")
    )
    ->leftJoin('awarded_contracts ac', function($q) {
        $q->on('cc.awarded_contract_id', '=', 'ac.id')
          ->on('ac.completion_date', '<', 'cc.actual_completion_date');
    })
    ->get();
```

Comment: Thank you. I thought you couldn't use more than one "on" in subqueries. I had to do something like "DB::table('completed contracts as cc ')" instead of "DB::table('completed contracts cc ')".